# Can I configure tomcat only to start certain webapps on startup?

Tags: tomcat

Can I configure Tomcat to start `myapp` but not `manager` when it is starting up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat by default deploys all applications inside `webapps` folder on startup. So a sloppy workaround might be to remove `manager`. 
A more elegant solution might be to alter `conf/server.xml` to ignore `manager` when deploying  applications on startup like this:

```
 <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" deployIgnore="manager">
```

The above Host configuration can be altered since `deployIgnore` value can be a regex. More information [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html)